# Show the same field twice, side by side, with different values

Tags: crystal-reports

How can I want print the same field twice with different value for each?

My Product and Shop tables are linked with product_id as the primary/foreign key.

```
Product
product_id
product_name

Shop
shop_id
product_id
quantity_product
```

When I use Expert Selection, I take all products on Shop_id 1 and Shop_id 2 (if Shop_id is in {1,2}...). Now I want to print 2 different quantity_product fields from Shop 1 and Shop 2 in the *same line* as my product_id. Something like:

```
product_name    quantity_product(shop_id: 1)    quantity_product(shop_id: 2)    
1               10                              20
```

I tried adding a new link in my database scheme with another Shop table, but it didn't work out.

Comment: Group by product id, create formulas to sum for shop1 and shop2. Of course this won't work if you have variable number of shops; then you could use crosstab.

Comment: @David Pham It's not necessary to say "Hi" or "Thanks" on StackOverflow posts. We prefer to edit them out for future visitors so they can skip past the pleasantries and solve the problem they came here for. (Assume everyone says hello and thank you even if they don't!)

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a CrossTab in the summary section to handle any number of Shops. (So long as there's room on the report for all the shop columns)

[image]

If that doesn't work you can manually set up a summary for each Shop:

[image: Summaries]

Keep in mind both of these solutions will need to be placed in a Footer section instead of the Details.